# angular-cli shows error saying the version is old

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I was working on one of my projects which is in Angular 2. I'm using the `angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.15` tool for building, testing, etc. I've recieved an error today when I was going to run and test the app.

> It seems like you're using a project generated using an old version of
>   the Angular CLI. The latest CLI now uses webpack and includes a lot of
>   improvements, include a simpler workflow, a faster build and smaller
>   bundles.
>
> To get more info, including a step-by-step guide to upgrade the CLI,
>   follow this link:
>   https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Upgrading-from-Beta.10-to-Beta.12

I was able to use the tool yesterday while I was building the app and I've done nothing unusual with it. I'm always running the cmd with admin rights and I've got angular-cli installed globally.

Thing I realized is a bit suspicious is that it shows me the 'old-version' error, while the version installed in my computer is the latest one (1.0.0-beta.15). I've checked the **package.json** file for som errors, but found nothing suspicious.

Here si the code if someone wants to have a look. Thanks in advance.

```
{
  "name": "oliwka-blog-final",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0"
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-imageupload": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-img-cropper": "^0.6.4",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",,
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.15",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.5",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've tried these steps:

1. reinstalling it globally
2. reinstalling it locally
3. cleaning npm cache
4. install it as dev-dependency

Also forgot to mention, that the tool works fine in other directories.

Comment: Please, show us your: npm -version and node -version

Comment: The question is already answered. The problem was in `angular-cli.json` file where project was set up to use angular-cli@-beta.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the project version in `angular-cli.json` or `.angular-cli.json`.

It should be something like:

`...
"project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.15",
    "name": "client"
}
...`

Comment: Where do you find this if it's not in the root dir?

Comment: If you're using angular-cli, angular-cli.json will be in the root directory. The latest version of the cli looks for `.angular-cli.json` but either should work.

Comment: Awesome thanks, I can see it yeah. Didn't see it because it's a dotfile